# Web Development workflow with git (1 and 1/2 programmers and 1 designer)

Tags: git, workflow

Half programmer here. :D

At this moment, the workflow resumes itself like this:

Messenger is on.
I code some things, and I upload them to a shared dev host and I see if it works.
The programmer code some things locally and then uploads to the shared dev host as well.
The designer puts some images that we request by messenger.

With msn in place, we say: upload this, download that... etc...

At the end, obviously, some overwrites or forgetting happens to arrive.

We all loved to avoid this.

So I'm thinking about:

- 1) The half programmer (me) - should
  start to code locally and not
  directly on the shared host
  development server.
- 2) Both programmers should have Git
  client installed and work with it.
- 3) We should register or little
  projects on Git Hub.
- 4) Both (programmer and the half
  thing) should start doing commits and
  other things using the repository
  instead of messaging each other.

With this I got two questions:

**A)** The development hosting server will be replaced by the git hub thing?

**B)** What about the graphic designer? Should he enter the work-flow somehow, so that, we all work on the same images as well?

*Any help about some more experienced developers with nice workflows is REALLY welcome. :)*

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 0):

The github stuff is totally optional. You could get init the a repo on the dev server and push directly to that.

Comment: :( The shared host don't have git support. I need github so I believe,because we are not working on the same physical space. (no LAN development).

Comment: If you don't have git on the dev machine having github isn't really going to help much. It's worth the effort to get this stuff really set up well. I can push code to production with with a single command or a few keystokes in my editor.

Comment: I can have git on the dev machine. I cannot have git on dev shared host machione. I now know we can connect both, still I want to avoid that. If I have to change the host, I'll change. But this is out of the question workflow scope that comprises both a) and b). But something I may asking wrong due to the lack of available options to this question. :(